# Failed to acquire global mutex lock with apache and mod_python

Tags: apache2, python

I have a web application that is being migrated from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.  I have followed all of the instructions that I normally would have done for setting this up in 14.04.  The application runs fine...as long as I don't logout of my ssh session, I start to get these errors when I do:

`(22)Invalid argument: Failed to acquire global mutex lock at index 7`

I have mpm_prefork enabled, mpm_event is disabled. (My instructions do not mention mpm_worker, but it is disabled as well)

**Apache is running as a local user (not www-data or root).**
When I run `ipcs -s` I see several semaphore arrays for this user.  If I log out of my ssh session and log back in, those semaphores are gone.  Coincidentally, if I start apache without logging in as that user, it works perfectly fine until someone logs in as that user and logs out.

I have confirmed that ipcrm is not being called when the semaphores are removed.

Comment: What about the solutions provided here: https://www.google.ch/search?q=mod_python+%22Failed+to+acquire+global+mutex+lock+at+index%22&oq=mod_python+%22Failed+to+acquire+global+mutex+lock+at+index%22
Does any of those answers lead you further

Comment: That is the first thing I did.  Most of the threads are over 10 years old, none of it is related to logging out.  .bash_logout has nothing relevant in it, /etc/bash.bash_logout is not present.  I suspect something was put in place to kill the users semaphores at logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to systemd-logind, which has *RemoveIPC=yes* set by default in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. Try setting it to *no*.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even see that.  I was in logind.conf messing around with KillUserProcesses and KillExcludeUsers but didn't make the connection between RemoveIPC and the ipc commands I was using to debug this.